# Upload csv to google sheets using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, csv, google-sheets

I want to upload a csv file to a google sheet at a particular cell. Since I need to upload a csv file to a certain cell I thought I would try to use selenium. I have a cell selected and the upload pop-up opened. But whenever I try to "send_keys" I get the "element not interactable" error. Is it possible that the upload element of type file is hidden?

My code:

```
#open upload popup
cell_location.send_keys('\ue03do')

#get iframe of upload popup
iframe_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[{}]/div[2]/iframe'.format(141))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_path)

time.sleep(1)
#navigate to upload file
upload = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":9"]/div')
upload.click()
time.sleep(1)
select_file = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":1f"]/div')
    
#pathetically attempt to upload file
time.sleep(1)
select_file.click()
select_file.send_keys('/Users/Documents/web_scaper/grant_proposals.csv')
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear! Thank you!

Comment: You know, Google Sheets has an API that lets you manipulate the spreadsheet cells directly.  You don't have to fake keystrokes and menu entries.

Comment: I know, but does it allow you to upload a csv file to a particular cell?

Comment: You load a local copy of the worksheet.  You can store whatever you want in whatever cell you want.  By the way, where is there a Sheets option to upload a CSV to a specific cell?  I don't see it.

Comment: If you click on a cell then go to file -- import -- upload -- replace data a selected cell. Perhaps I should just download the csv from google sheets, then do all the edits I want, and then re-upload the whole thing. I would like to be able to upload a csv through selenium though. Maybe it's not possible.

Comment: Not impossible, but certainly difficult, and very delicate, since it depends on Google keeping the same HTML until eternity.  Either the API or the download/fix/upload solutions will be more stable.

Comment: Would you be open to an answer using [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) and/or [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive)? You basically just want to upload this CSV file to Google Sheets right?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying a lot of different things to make this work somehow. Finally found the solution.

You're not supposed to click on the "Upload" button itself, underneath it, you will see a input with inspect element.
Just copy the XPath of that input element, that is where you do .send_keys("file path").

Here's the example:

```
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/input')
```